# Get current controller and action name in Ramaze

Tags: ruby, ramaze

Is there a way to get the currently executing controller and action name in Ramaze?

```
require 'ramaze'

class FooController < Ramaze::Controller
  def bar
    "#{controller}.#{action}" #how to get this to work?
  end
end
```

PS: I know `self.class.name` would give you the class name/controller name but was wondering if this captured somewhere else in the Ramaze API. Also `__method__` should give the action name but I don't want to create variables when I pass this info to templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them with :

```
controller = action.node
method = action.method
```

See https://github.com/Ramaze/ramaze/wiki/Knowing-which-controller-or-method-triggered-view-layout-rendering

Comment: Btw, can you also please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686664/using-content-for-and-yield-content-in-ramaze